# Force child class to override function of ancestor via parent

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am writing an algorithm which requires the user to create his own class which inherits from a class defined by me. However, the algorithm requires the user to override the Equals and GetHashCode functions from the C# standard libraries.

Can I force the class inherited from my class to implement the GetHashCode and Equals functions?

```
public abstract int GetHashCode();
```

Writing this in my base class is not an option, as my base class inherits GetHashCode from it's parent, where it is implemented already.

Comment: Is your class abstract?

Comment: Yes, my class is abstract. New functions defined abstract in this class work as I want.

Comment: "I am writing an algorithm which requires the user to create his own class which inherits from a class defined by me". Stop now. Inheritance is bad enough, without forcing people to use it. Define an interface. Let them write their own classes. Be nice.

Comment: However, the algorithm will simply not work if you do not implement both functions. This is why I want to force users to implement them.

Comment: and that is why an interface is called a contract

Comment: @AartStuurman: Interfaces force the implementation of methods.  The code won't compile otherwise.

Comment: @Wim - Every class has an implementation of GetHashCode and Equals.  Putting these methods into an interface is meaningless, since every class will already have these methods defined from the object class.

Comment: @WimOmbelets public abstract override int GetHashCode(); seems to be what I am looking for(Sriram's answer). I do not see why I would use an interface instead of this. Could you eleborate?

Comment: very bad judgement call on my behalf. I wrongfully expected that implementing an interface with e.g. GetHashCode() would be possible and would force the user to re-implement the method. Wow. I'm gonna take a nap now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what you're looking for. Since your class is abstract you can pretty much do this without any problem.

```
public abstract override int GetHashCode();
```

This despite of it derived from some other class, this makes your sub class must override this method.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, indeed. At least it compiled, so I will test if it does what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can create 2 new methods that will be abstract and will be called from `GetHashCode` and `Equals` your class.

Example:

```
public abstract ParentClass {
    public abstract int MyGetHashCode();

    public override int GetHashCode(){
        return MyGetHashCode();
    }

    // same thing for Equals
}
```

Comment: This was my second option, although I do not like helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your class:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

This means that if they don't override it the function will fail by exception. This forces them to override it to get it to work.

Comment: This is also a very interesting option. If I cannot find another way, I will give this a try.